# Basic system supplied audio unit implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio, audiounit

I'd love it if someone could post or direct me to a simple implementation of one of the system supplied Audio Units. I'm looking to use the AUPitch in with iOS (does iPhone even support that unit?) and there doesn't appear to be any simple description of how to use it.

Thanks in advance,

mIL3S

http://www.milkdrinkingcow.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, AUPitch is not available on iOS.  yoknapatawpha's reference to the [Dirac library](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html) is a good one, but there's a lot more to Audio Unit implementation than one might assume from Justin's post.  I'd recommend the following resources:

- Apple's [Audio Unit Hosting Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) - You  *must* read this--nothing anyone says will make sense until you do.
- Easily number two on this list, Chris Adamson's [Core Audio Brain Dump](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2009/04/28/an-iphone-core-audio-brain-dump/).
- This [talk and set of tutorials](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/04/30/what-you-missed-at-360idev/) from 360iDev - Easily the least referenced and most helpful guide I found along the way.
- Michael Tyson's [intro to the Remote I/O Unit](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/) - Easily the *most* referenced guide I found--but be warned, he leaves more than a few blanks for you to fill in on your own.
- This [helpful guide](http://timbolstad.com/2010/03/14/core-audio-getting-started/) from Tim Bolstad
- This is a helpful [open-source project](http://code.google.com/p/grid-iphone/source/browse/trunk/Classes/DJMixer.m) I that found helpful to pick apart.
- [Another project](http://iphonedev.com/app/grid-iphone) I picked apart in my learning.
- And, [a third](https://github.com/coryalder/SineWaver)...
- There are also plenty of sample projects in the SDK's example code.  Most are quite ambitious, and can be nothing better than labyrinthine if you're not experienced with C++.  Excellent resources, though, if you've the know-how.  If you're confident, check out aurioTouch--this shows you the structures necessary to pass audio off to something like Dirac.
- And, make sure to utilise the [coreaudio-api](http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/coreaudio-api) mailing list, as well.

Were I to go back and start from scratch, I wouldn't touch anything until I'd thoroughly read the first three.  The Apple docs can be a pain to sort through, but read the one referenced here *cover to cover*.  I can't count the number of things that didn't work for me that I only found a solution for when I realised I'd missed that detail in the Audio Unit Hosting Guide by just deciding, "Oh, I'll just give this a shot"...  Do use those resources, and come back when you've got more questions!

Comment: Did this answer your question?  If so, go ahead and accept.  Or, if someone else's was more helpful to you, go ahead and give them the tip of the cap...

Comment: Ack I never marked your answer! So sorry! Better late than never. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a definitive statement in the Apple docs (check [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH10-SW10)) but I'm pretty certain that most of the AudioUnits supplied with OSX are unavailable in iOS. (This topic has also come up several times on the Core Audio mailing list.)

For an audio pitch-shifting solution on iOS, I would recommend Dirac 3 or the Rubber Band library.

Comment: The Core Audio mailing list can be found here: http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/coreaudio-api and here are links to Dirac 3 - http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html - and Rubber Band: http://www.breakfastquay.com/rubberband/

Comment: "iPhone OS provides three audio units: a Converter unit (of type (AUConverter), a 3D Embedded Mixer unit (of type AU3DEmbeddedMixer), and an IO Remote unit (of type AUIORemote). Use the interfaces in the Audio Unit framework to open, connect, and use audio units in iPhone OS.

iPhone OS does not support the creation of audio units."

From: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/index.html%23PROCESSING-USE_THE_BUILT_IN_AUDIO_UNITS_IN_IPHONE_OS

Answer (score 0):

if you find no sample, all you have to do to use this au is to create an au graph/renderer, then add the au you want, set its parameters, render, etc... i'm assuming there are examples provided by apple which walk you through this.

from there:

see AudioUnitParameters.h of the sdk you're targeting for documentation of each parameter for the system AUs.

an excerpt of what to look for:

```
// Parameters for the AUBandpass unit
enum {
        // Global, Hz, 20->(SampleRate/2), 5000
    kBandpassParam_CenterFrequency          = 0,

        // Global, Cents, 100->12000, 600
    kBandpassParam_Bandwidth                = 1
};

// Some parameters for the AUGraphicEQ unit
enum {
        // Global, Indexed, currently either 10 or 31
    kGraphicEQParam_NumberOfBands           = 10000
};

// Parameters for the AUHipass unit
enum {
        // Global, Hz, 10->(SampleRate/2), 6900
    kHipassParam_CutoffFrequency            = 0,

        // Global, dB, -20->40, 0
    kHipassParam_Resonance                  = 1
};
```

good luck